# Should I use mixed RAM and/or fill all RAM slots?

Tags: memory

I want to upgrade my laptop's RAM. Currently, I have 16 GB (2x8 GB) RAM, and I want to upgrade it to 32 GB.

My computer has 4 RAM slots (SODIMM), 2 is already filled. In the internet, I've read that filling all 4 slots could cause performance issues and also using mixed RAMs (size, MHz, brand) is not a good idea.

The tech support guy from Dell recommended me to buy another 2x8 GB RAMs and install it but the RAMs I can buy from Dell's website are 2666 MHz and currently I have 2400 MHz RAMs.

I was thinking of buying another 16 GB and installing it in the 3rd slot but I have no idea what dual channeling is. People say it is really bad to use 3 slots.

As you see, I am really confused. What should I do to upgrade my device's RAM?

Thanks and stay safe.

Comment: Even it it has 4 slots you may not be able to use them all. Some RAM modules are one physical module but on data level they act as they were two (dual rank). When using such modules the second slot of each each module has to be left unused. Use CPU-Z for reading out details on your current RAM modules.

Comment: you should follow the recommendations for the motherboard. if it is a Dell laptop (as you said you contacted their support) I would go with those. as Robert says, you need to have a valid configuration. CPU-Z will show you the current setup, but will not tell what configurations will/would work. Some MBs will allow a mix (not all types of mixes) of speed/size/slot fillment. For dual channel just search and you will find a lot of resources, in short - multi-channel has speed improvements in comparison with single-channel setups.

Comment: If prices there are anywhere near what they are in the Netherlands, I would definitely not order from Dell itself. Here 16GB DDR4, 2666MHz is 190 euros, whereas 32GB of Crucial RAM is 130 euros. In that case I'd just order 32GB from crucial. Use their upgrade compatibility tool to check which modules are compatible to your laptop. https://www.crucial.com/upgrades

Comment: @BramMooij - I do not see anyone saying to buy from Dell, only to follow the suggestion to fill all 4 slots with same sized modules.

Comment: @Zina, it's a response to this part in the question : "RAMs I can buy from Dell's website are 2666 MHz and currently I have 2400 MHz RAMs.". That suggests the OP was considering ordering from Dell,which in my opinion is a waste of money.

Comment: got me there :) I was only looking at the comments & answers. My bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mix RAM with different clock rates](https://superuser.com/questions/801259/mix-ram-with-different-clock-rates)

Answer (score 2):

In general, mixing RAM brands is usually fine, though there sometimes are weird incompatibilities so it's *preferred* to use the same brands.

**Dual Channel** is when any two sticks of RAM are inserted (so a 4gb stick and an 8gb stick together would be "4gb dual channel" because only 4gb are 'shared'). Dual channel configurations give you a nice performance boost, usually.

Then there is RAM speed. If you get 2666MHz RAM and you have 2400MHz RAM, the 2666MHz RAM should automatically run at the slower 2400MHz speed.

Use CPU-Z to check if you have dual rank RAM (which means you should probably leave one slot empty for each dual rank RAM stick).

If not, then I would go with what the Dell guy recommended, 2x8GB RAM from either the Dell site or somewhere else (like Crucial). Even if it is a higher speed, it should automatically run slower, and you get the dual channel performance.

Comment: There are quite a lot of conflicting advices to be found on this subject. Therefore, I would say it's extra important to provide some reliable sources. Many people say you should keep all the RAM sticks identical to use dual-channel. Some disagree, but because of the lack of soures it's not clear to me whether it works in 5% or 95-100% of cases. Therefore, it would be good if you have some reliable sources to back your statement up.

Comment: @BramMooij That's true, I'll get some sources

Answer (score 0):

You can fill and mix ram slots.however the slowest ram stick will be the one to dictate the speed through the ram portal.As Aman mentioned you run the risk of errors. Never heard of such a thing of bad idea when it comes to filling all 4 slots.I find that hard to believe.
I use CPU-Z, but rely on Speecy , which can be found pretty much everywhere.Speecy gives a very good detail of slots,speeds, and a lot more then CPU-Z. Hope this helps.

Comment: not all MBs will allow mixing. and OP did not say it is a "bad idea'" to fill out all slots, he probably was thinking for the future if he will want to  expand with more RAM.