# Bluescreen after RAM upgrading (same brand, only different MHz and CL)

Tags: windows, memory, bios, asus

I recently added the following RAM to my setting and had one blue screen:

- 2 x 32 GB FURY Beast DDR5 **5600 MHz CL 40**

​

My setting setting (*running over a year without a single problem*):

- ASUS ROG Z690 Formula
- i9-1200KS
- 2 x 32 GB FURY Beast DDR5 **4800 MHz CL 38**

​

I am now afraid that I get more blue screens. I actually thought that I could easily mix these two sorts of RAM ([and that the 5600 would be slowed down to 4800](https://superuser.com/questions/801259/mix-ram-with-different-clock-rates)). In my ASUS Bios setting, everything is set to auto mode.

Would it be better to somehow set RAM settings to other than auto with my new RAM?

Comment: Standard question - did you take correct anti esd precautions, and no, momentarily touching metal every so often does not count. If not, then who knows what damage you have done to any number of components. A basic wrist strap would cost you less than $10 to protect equipment which may cost you a couple of thousands.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did. The system is running now for about 12h without a bluescreen. I think the ASUS Bios does some AI tweaking of the RAM with the auto mode setting. Is there a chance that it did something wrong (that caused the bluescreen) and corrected it now?

Comment: Is there no xmp setting rather than auto?

Comment: There is. But I was afraid that manual settings would slow down the performance?

Comment: I thought the auto settings would be the safest for my setting where only MHz and CL differ